# Flutter MLKIT Text Recognition Extract a Specified Line

Tags: flutter, ocr, google-mlkit, text-recognition

How can i Extract a Line from Flutter ML Kit Text Recognition ?

[image: Example Image for Recognition]

I wanna extract the Line from "SUMME" i need only this line as double Variable,

```
    List recognedText = [];
  bool textScanning = false;
  var scannedText = "Scanned Text will be shown here".obs;
  takeImageforScan() async {
    recognedText.clear();
    try {
      textScanning = true;
      final pickedImage =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        textScanning = true;
        final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(pickedImage.path);
        final recognizer = GoogleMlKit.vision.textRecognizer();
        final visionText = await recognizer.processImage(
          inputImage,
        );
        //scannedText.value = visionText.text;
        recognizer.close();
        textScanning = false;

         for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        recognedText.add(block.text);
        //Extract the Summe Line from the Text
        if (line.text.contains("Summe")) {
          recognedText.add(line.text);
        }
      }
    }
  }
      }
      print(recognedText);
      Get.to(() => const RegisterAutomat());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);

      textScanning = false;
      Get.snackbar(
          "Fehler", "Keine Daten gefunden,bitte tragen Sie manuell ein");
    }
  }
```

Its returning Actually the List from the Image all of Texts,
but i wanna extract only a Price from Summe (Total Price) , i think i have to extract it from the returned Text List , or can i make it with AI Package ?
OUTPUT From Flutter

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter ( 3895): 0
I/flutter ( 3895): Creating Screen für(1)
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ........ 0,0-960,2613} of ViewRootImpl@6c1a062[MainActivity]
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ........ 0,0-960,2613}
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): windowStopped(true) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ........ 0,0-960,2613} of ViewRootImpl@6c1a062[MainActivity]
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-960,2613} of ViewRootImpl@6c1a062[MainActivity]
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): windowStopped(false) true io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-960,2613} of ViewRootImpl@6c1a062[MainActivity]
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): surfaceCreated 1 #1 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-960,2613}
I/SurfaceView@c9d0980( 3895): surfaceChanged (960,2613) 1 #1 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{c9d0980 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-960,2613}
I/flutter ( 3895): [ETRON Soft wareentwicklungs -und
I/flutter ( 3895): Vertriebs Gmbh, ETRON Soft wareentwicklungs -und
I/flutter ( 3895): Vertriebs Gmbh, Text, Kassa -ID: 152 ("Natalie4")
I/flutter ( 3895): Sitzungs-ID: POS15201-000002
I/flutter ( 3895): Druckdatum: 28.01. 2021 12:00:47
I/flutter ( 3895): Abschluss durch: johann
I/flutter ( 3895): 4 Belege K15201/20- 000053 bis
I/flutter ( 3895): K15201/20 - 000056, Kassa -ID: 152 ("Natalie4")
I/flutter ( 3895): Sitzungs-ID: POS15201-000002
I/flutter ( 3895): Druckdatum: 28.01. 2021 12:00:47
I/flutter ( 3895): Abschluss durch: johann
I/flutter ( 3895): 4 Belege K15201/20- 000053 bis
I/flutter ( 3895): K15201/20 - 000056, Kassa -ID: 152 ("Natalie4")
I/flutter ( 3895): Sitzungs-ID: POS15201-000002
I/flutter ( 3895): Druckdatum: 28.01. 2021 12:00:47
I/flutter ( 3895): Abschluss durch: johann
I/flutter ( 3895): 4 Belege K15201/20- 000053 bis
I/flutter ( 3895): K15201/20 - 000056, Kassa -ID: 152 ("Natalie4")
I/flutter ( 3895): Sitzungs-ID: POS15201-000002
I/flutter ( 3895): Druckdatum: 28.01. 2021 12:00:47
I/flutter ( 3895): Abschluss durch: johann
I/flutter ( 3895): 4 Belege K15201/20- 000053 bis
I/flutter ( 3895): K15201/20 - 000056, Kassa -ID: 152 ("Natalie4")
I/flutter ( 3895): Sitzungs-ID: POS15201-000002
I/flutter ( 3895): Druckdatum: 28.01. 2021 12:00:47
I/flutter ( 3895): Abschluss durch: johann
I/flutter ( 3895): 4 Belege K15201/20- 000053 bis
I/flutter ( 3895): K15201/20 - 000056, Kassa -ID: 152 ("Natalie4")
I/flutter ( 3895): Sitzungs-ID: POS15201-000002
I/flutter ( 3895): Druckdatum: 28.01. 2021 12:00:47
I/flutter ( 3895): Abs
```

Comment: Umm. Remove `recognedText.add(block.text)`?

Comment: This is only a List that i can see what its added ? I wanna only know how can i add a complete Line in a String then i can Parse it Like "SUMME:" and "100.00€"

Comment: Like I said remove that line, then only add/parse inside of `if (line.text.contains("Summe"))`... But that's case sensitive. So, did you try SUMME there? Why do you need a list?

Comment: I removed this line , and i tried also if with "SUMME" then extracting only SUMME , i think its not understanding that ist a Line, because its has too mucht space for Line,
SUMME                                       963,00 €
Its extracting two different Variable as Summe and 963,00 €

Comment: Correct. The ocr scanner sees *sections* of text, or `TextBlock`, not "lines"... You'd need to find the block starting with `Umsatz exkl`, then parse each sub-block to find the "last SUMME line", along with the values on the right

Comment: Can you write a Codeblock for me  ? I can not understand what u mean about the CodeBlock ? Thx. Because the Umsatz exkl. text has got more Values like 3 another Prices, how can flutter choice about the Correct Variable ? You mean that i parse all Blocks, and find that starting with Umsatz Exkl. then in this block find Summe Line after that find it still no Price it shows again Summe ? if i parse it as Text Line then its returning again the same Var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer - I dont know Flutter

Looking at your code, you have

```
for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
```

This loops over **blocks** of text, not "lines". For example, all text in the "header" of the image may be "one block", but not necessarily "multiple lines"

However, you do have

```
for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
```

And this should loop over any line-breaks found within that block.

Then, text found by image recognition is case-sensitive, so you want

```
if (line.text.contains("SUMME")) {
```

**However**, there is no guarantee that the `5.401,73` is on that same `line`, or even the same `block`, because the image contains multiple blocks of text. You'll need to do more debugging to find which block that number exists.

**And** there are multiple `SUMME` in your image. Therefore, you should **also** be checking the block/line that contains `Umsatz`, for example.

```
if (block.lines[0].text.contains("Umsatz")) {
  for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
    if (line.text.contains("SUMME")) {
       print(line.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "There are multiple SUMME in your image..." - The necessary SUMME is the first one in the image. That might simplify finding it.